# Can't load .css and image files in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I can't load images and css files in django, although everything seems to be fine in settings.py and in the home.html file itself... what can be a problem here?

In  the static folder there are `template`, `css` and `image` folders.

HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
<title>Main Page</title>
```

settings.py:

```
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/media")
#MEDIA_URL = ''
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static")
]
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this:
[image: web page in Russian with no css formatting and broken images]

Comment: There are several things that can be improperly set. What path are your css and images files in? are you serving your app with `./manage.py runserver` or another method? Is debug set to `True`?

Answer (score 1):

`django.contrib.staticfiles` is not included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Your `settings.py` should look like this (in INSTALLED APPS)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

without that static files won't work even if everything else is setup properly because to django it's not installed even though it is (Technically).